# writing into shared arrays within a distributed for loop in JULIA

Tags: julia, differential-equations, plots.jl, differentialequations.jl

I have an ODE that I need to solver over a wide range of parameters.
Previously I have used MATLAB's parfor to divide the parameter ranges between multiple threads. I am new to Julia and need to do the same thing in Julia now. Here is the code that I am using

```
using DifferentialEquations, SharedArrays, Distributed, Plots


function SingleBubble(du,u,p,t)
    du[1]=@. u[2]
    du[2]=@. ((-0.5*u[2]^2)*(3-u[2]/(p[4]))+(1+(1-3*p[7])*u[2]/p[4])*((p[6]-p[5])/p[2]+2*p[1]/(p[2]*p[8]))*(p[8]/u[1])^(3*p[7])-2*p[1]/(p[2]*u[1])-4*p[3]*u[2]/(p[2]*u[1])-(1+u[2]/p[4])*(p[6]-p[5]+p[10]*sin(2*pi*p[9]*t))/p[2]-p[10]*u[1]*cos(2*pi*p[9]*t)*2*pi*p[9]/(p[2]*p[4]))/((1-u[2]/p[4])*u[1]+4*p[3]/(p[2]*p[4]))
end

R0=2e-6
f=2e6
u0=[R0,0]
LN=1000

RS = SharedArray(zeros(LN))
P = SharedArray(zeros(LN))
bif = SharedArray(zeros(LN,6))

 @distributed     for i= 1:LN
    ps=1e3+i*1e3
    tspan=(0,60/f)
    p=[0.0725,998,1e-3,1481,0,1.01e5,7/5,R0,f,ps]
    prob = ODEProblem(SingleBubble,u0,tspan,p)
    sol=solve(prob,Tsit5(),alg_hints=:stiff,saveat=0.01/f,reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8)
    RS[i]=maximum((sol[1,5000:6000])/R0)
    P[i]=ps
    for j=1:6
          nn=5500+(j-1)*100;
          bif[i,j]=(sol[1,nn]/R0);
     end
end


plotly()
scatter(P/1e3,bif,shape=:circle,ms=0.5,label="")#,ma=0.6,mc=:black,mz=1,label="")
```

When using one worker, the for loop is basically executed as a normal single threaded loop and it works fine. However, when I am using addprocs(n) to add n more workers, nothing gets written into the SharedArrays RS, P and bif. I appreciate any guidance anyone may provide.

Comment: Can you show how are you using addprocs(n) in your code?

Comment: Before running the above code, I execute addprocs(4) in the terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These changes are required to make your program work with multiple workers and display the results you need:

1. Whatever packages and functions are used under `@distributed` loop must be made available in all the processes using `@everywhere` as explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/index.html#Code-Availability-and-Loading-Packages-1). So, in your case it would be `DifferentialEquations` and `SharedArrays` packages as well as the `SingleBubble()` function.
2. You need to draw the plot only after all the workers have finished their tasks. For this, you would need to use [`@sync`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/#Base.@sync) along with `@distributed`.

With these changes, your code would look like:

```
using Distributed, Plots

@everywhere using DifferentialEquations, SharedArrays

@everywhere function SingleBubble(du,u,p,t)
    du[1]=@. u[2]
    du[2]=@. ((-0.5*u[2]^2)*(3-u[2]/(p[4]))+(1+(1-3*p[7])*u[2]/p[4])*((p[6]-p[5])/p[2]+2*p[1]/(p[2]*p[8]))*(p[8]/u[1])^(3*p[7])-2*p[1]/(p[2]*u[1])-4*p[3]*u[2]/(p[2]*u[1])-(1+u[2]/p[4])*(p[6]-p[5]+p[10]*sin(2*pi*p[9]*t))/p[2]-p[10]*u[1]*cos(2*pi*p[9]*t)*2*pi*p[9]/(p[2]*p[4]))/((1-u[2]/p[4])*u[1]+4*p[3]/(p[2]*p[4]))
end

R0=2e-6
f=2e6
u0=[R0,0]
LN=1000

RS = SharedArray(zeros(LN))
P = SharedArray(zeros(LN))
bif = SharedArray(zeros(LN,6))

@sync @distributed     for i= 1:LN
    ps=1e3+i*1e3
    tspan=(0,60/f)
    p=[0.0725,998,1e-3,1481,0,1.01e5,7/5,R0,f,ps]
    prob = ODEProblem(SingleBubble,u0,tspan,p)
    sol=solve(prob,Tsit5(),alg_hints=:stiff,saveat=0.01/f,reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8)
    RS[i]=maximum((sol[1,5000:6000])/R0)
    P[i]=ps
    for j=1:6
          nn=5500+(j-1)*100;
          bif[i,j]=(sol[1,nn]/R0);
     end
end


plotly()
scatter(P/1e3,bif,shape=:circle,ms=0.5,label="")#,ma=0.6,mc=:black,mz=1,label="")
```

Output using multiple workers:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! this solved it.
I have a machine that can handle 64 workers and the package loading process on all of them takes quite a while. is there way to speed this up?

Comment: Change the topology in addprocs

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I am very new to Julia. Can you please be a bit more descriptive? I know I can use CuArrays to solve ODEs on GPU. How can I solve an ODE with different initial conditions in parallel on GPU?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @The Hossein wait a bit on that. We will release it with a blog post explaining how to use it in about 2 months

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas awesome! thank you for the heads up!